# ECASH transaction to the ECH Token Address on Metamask

Tags: meta-transactions

I bought some Ecash from etherdelta and transfered to my Metamask wallet but the token address belongs to ECH that'swhy i did'nt get my fund. Is there any possibility to get my fund back?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have spent ether and it has been mined, there is no way to get it back unless the receiver sends it back to you. This is how blockchain works.

Comment: But i sent my tokens to my ECH address not to another person.

Comment: ECH? Do you have a transaction hash? If you sent it to an exchange wallet, it's lost.

Comment: yes i have TX hash...what can i do with this Tx hash?

Comment: Send it here, so we can investigate. But if you sent your tokens to an address you dont control theyre probably lost